# Sorting words in a string by their length in J

Tags: string, sorting, j

I have the following string:
s=:'when can we dance'
I can find the length of each word with this:
`# each ;:s`
I can sort the lengths in ascending/descending order:`(/:~) # each ;:s` which gives me boxed output.
But how do I get the words printed?

Comment: Expected output: (for ascending order): we can when dance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julian does a great job of explaining the way to deal with apostrophes in his answer above, but if you disregard their presence, I would use `&.` (Under) with `;:` (Words) to sort them according to length after they are boxed and then unboxing them.

```
   s=:'when can we dance' 
   (/:  # each)  &. ;: s
we can when dance
```

`(/:  # each)` is the hook that orders them according to each length and `&.;:` boxes them and then at the end unboxes them to provide the result.

Answer (score 4):

You're already using `/:~` which is the [Reflex](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/tilde) of dyadic [Sort Up](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/slashco#dyadic); `/:~ y` is equivalent to `y /: y`. This is a convenient shortcut, but it this case what you're skipping past is the solution you're looking for. `/:` (without Reflex) permutes its `x` according to the permutation that would result in a sorted `y`. That "permutation that would result in a sorted `y`" is incidentally what monadic `/:`
([Grade Up](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/slashco)) is for.

```
   ]w=:;:'when can we dance'
+----+---+--+-----+
|when|can|we|dance|
+----+---+--+-----+
   /: w
1 3 2 0
   (/: w) { w
+---+-----+--+----+
|can|dance|we|when|
+---+-----+--+----+
   w /: w
+---+-----+--+----+
|can|dance|we|when|
+---+-----+--+----+
```

So to sort `w` by something else, like the lengths of its items, just provide that something else as Sort Up's `y`:

```
   w /: # each w
+--+---+----+-----+
|we|can|when|dance|
+--+---+----+-----+
   (/: # each) w     NB. a hook
+--+---+----+-----+
|we|can|when|dance|
+--+---+----+-----+
```

`;:` gives you the *J* words in a string, which might not be what you want:

```
   ;: 'when can''t we dance'
|open quote
|       ;:'when can''t we dance'
```

One of the `;.` [Cut](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/semidot) family or [stdlib's](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Standard_Library/strings) `splitstring` or [regexes](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Studio/Regular_Expressions) might help.

```
   13 : ';: ''when can we dance'''  NB. 13 : can be a mnemonic
(<;._1 ' when can we dance')"_

   <;._1 ' ','when can''t we dance'
+----+-----+--+-----+
|when|can't|we|dance|
+----+-----+--+-----+
   ' ' splitstring 'when can''t we dance'
+----+-----+--+-----+
|when|can't|we|dance|
+----+-----+--+-----+

   s=:'when can''t   we dance'  NB. excess space
   <;._1 ' ',s  NB. empty boxes in result
+----+-----+++--+-----+
|when|can't|||we|dance|
+----+-----+++--+-----+
   require 'regex'
   '[\w'']+' rxall s
+----+-----+--+-----+
|when|can't|we|dance|
+----+-----+--+-----+
```

To get these word-lists back into a string,

```
   w
+----+---+--+-----+
|when|can|we|dance|
+----+---+--+-----+
   ;: inv w
when can we dance
   ' ' joinstring w
when can we dance
```

Comment: Thank you Julian for pointing out what J offers in terms of library support for string manipulation.